# Xamarin Deploy to Device

Tags: android, xamarin

While trying to debug my application i am getting below error, any one have idea about it?

```
Deployment failed because of an internal error: No such file or directory

Deployment failed. Internal error.
```

Comment: Does this happen with any project, or just one in particular?

Comment: Try changing the API level of your Emulator, assuming you're using one

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS, go to Tool => Options => Projects and Solutions => Build and Run, and set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to either detailed or diagnostic then try to deploy again and check the output window for more info about the error you're getting. If you're still puzzled with the additional info, post here so we can help you.